# Website not visible from only 1 office

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall

Small website for our company is visible from every location except from computers in our office.

Ive ruled out everything I can think of, including :

Firewall. m0m0wall, very basic straightforward setup. I want to remove it and test, but powers above me say no, firewall is not the problem.

Hosting company reports everything working as intended, as evidenced by the site loads for everyone else. (Points finger at office, I agree)

Internet connection (Cox) ruled out, as other traffic flows.

Internet gateway ruled out by powers above me (Im betting the problem is there but need ammo).

Ideas?

Comment: What error do you get?  The error is usually the first clue as to where the fault lies.  Possible errors are: hostname not found (DNS resolution), HTTP 502 or 504 response (local proxy), HTTP 403 response (maybe local proxy), connection refused or connection timeout ( probably local firewall ).  There are more possible responses and reasons.  Tell us what you get.

Comment: Connection timeout is what were seeing. I am still looking over everything. Im having to do some research, Im a programmer not a routing expert lol! I will report back tomorrow AM with what I find.

Comment: FIXED!!!!  Hosting company blacklisted their IP due to too many login failures. Third guy I talked to there discovered this. I should have asked them more questions.

Answer (score 3):

Check DNS resolution

- dig/nslookup the domain name and see what the response is. (Remember to use different DNS servers. Use the ones that are official for your LAN and then use externally hosted DNS servers like OpenDNS (`208.67.220.220`) or Google (`8.8.4.4`).

Check IP connectivity

- traceroute the destination IP and see if you can communicate at the network layer. If not, see where the communication breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
Small website for our company is visible from every location except from computers
in our office.
```

does not define the error precisely. You can try the following:

1. If you are getting name resolution error such as `can not find name`, this means you have DNS issue. Then, you can try to access the website using IP. If that works, you need to check your configured DNS server.
2. If you are getting connection error such as `can not connect` or `can not establish connection` or similar, you need to make sure you are connecting to the website using the appropriate IP address and that IP is reachable from your office.

To check connectivity, you can use `ping server_ip`. Also, you can try `telnet server_ip 80` for http and `telnet server_ip 443` for https.

After doing these checks, you can narrow down the problem possible causes.